# How many lines can a css file contain?

Tags: css, coding-style

How many lines can a css file have (practically) for good maintainability? I am dealing with a css file which has 15K plus lines. I want a recommendation on this.

Comment: 15k? ... How? Are you duplicating styles and making minor changes?
Perhaps SASS is something to look in to. With SASS you can split your css in to smaller chunks without having to load several different styleshets on clientside.

Comment: I just inherited the code. I think there are duplicating styles. I will look into SASS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an **.css** file is unlimited.

Comment: That wasn't the question. The question was how many it can have practically for good maintainability. Which will generate primairly oppinion based answers, therefor it will most likely be closed.

Comment: This is the right answer to your main question. "How many lines can a css file contain?"

Comment: It's the right answer to the title, the question is defined in the descriptive text.

Comment: guidelines for maintainability is in the heart of software development. The answers will be opinion based but backed with logic as well. It will be a bad judgement to close this one on that count. Stackoverflow has had questions on coding guidelines.

Comment: Technically, it's not correct. It would depend on your computer resources and browser used. But I'm not aware of any limit **specified** anywhere, so your answer is correct in theoretical sense.

Answer (score 1):

Like most files, CSS files can obviously be as long as you want. For improved loading times, and like you mention, for ease of maintainability, the shorter the CSS file the better.

15K lines sounds excessive. Where possible, whenever coding, you want to try and follow the general rule of 'never repeat yourself'. There are probably styles in that file that are very similar to one another or just not necessary. I'd recommend (a slightly arduous task) attempting to compress the file as much as possible, and combine or remove styles.

I don't think there is any definitive good practice limit to CSS file sizes. I've never needed one that is longer that 3000 lines, but a very complex site might require a file larger than that. The basic rule is try to make the CSS file as short as possible to achieve what you need to achieve.

Comment: I am not a css developer but I want to know the code smells in our codebase. Thanks for your input : this gives me an idea that beyond 3000 lines is not practical except for rare cases. Besides, I think there are plenty of issues in our css styles like "Do not repeat yourself".